# Printing all subsets in C using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, algorithm, subset, dynamic-memory-allocation

Printing all subsets in C
I tried to create a function that prints all subsets of a given set using c. However it does not work as expected. While it prints the first ten subarrays , some problems, which are probably due to memory allocations, appear afterwards. Therefore, I wanted to ask for help.

The Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void printArray(int* arr,int size){
    for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        printf("%d ",arr[i]);
    }
    printf("%d\n",arr[size-1]);
}
void subsetUtil(int *arr,int *subset,int index,int arrSize,int Subsize){
    printArray(subset,Subsize);
    for(int i=index;i<arrSize;i++){
        int* temp = malloc((1 + Subsize) * sizeof(int));
        memcpy(temp, subset, Subsize * sizeof(int));
        temp[Subsize]=arr[i];
        subset=malloc((1 + Subsize) * sizeof(int));
        memcpy(subset,temp,(1 + Subsize) * sizeof(int));
        free(temp);
        subsetUtil(arr,subset,i+1,arrSize,Subsize+1);
        int *newTemp=malloc(Subsize*sizeof(int));
        memcpy(newTemp,subset,Subsize);
        subset=malloc(Subsize*sizeof(int));
        memcpy(subset,newTemp,Subsize*sizeof(int));
        free(newTemp);
    }
    free(subset);
}
void printAllSubsets(int* arr,int size){
    int index=0;
    int subset[1];
    subsetUtil(arr,subset,index,size,1);
}
int main(void){
    int baseArray[10]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};
    printAllSubsets(baseArray,10);
    return 0;
}
```

What I am expecting is a solution for my code. I dont want to change the algo as I am sure that it will work. The problem is probably based on the way I using the algo, therefore I am looking for help.

Comment: `int subset[1];` looks suspicious.

Comment: This is the one particular algorithm I wanna use: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-to-find-all-subsets/

Comment: I also tried changing subset[1] and it does not seem to haven an effect all over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are doing `newTemp=malloc(Subsize*sizeof(int))` and then `memcpy(newTemp,subset,Subsize)` while it should be `memcpy(newTemp,subset,Subsize*sizeof(int))`.

It causes an error because `Subsize` as a memory size is (usually) in bytes while `Subsize*sizeof(int)` is the number of integers (usually 4 bytes each) you want. Hence all the nonsense being printed after a few iterations.

Sorry if my answer is a little bit short but I'm on my phone so I can't really do that much more.